# Should "actually" and "really" be blacklisted in titles?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

See also "[Is there *really* a reason why so many questions *really* need to include the word 'really'?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/445/is-there-really-a-reason-why-so-many-questions-really-need-to-include-the-wo)" for the reasons why using these two adverbs is not good for this site.

I periodically go through the list of questions and delete basically all usages of "really" and "actually" from the titles. Whilst there are a very few cases in which the use of these adverbs is warranted, I'd like to blacklist these words. Users that really need to use them can use a circumlocution (e.g. "Users that have a concrete necessity to use them...", see what I did there?)

The effect would be similar to this, the text has some customization for guidance.

[image: test of blacklist effect on title]

What do you think?

Comment: What would message would the user get when trying to submit a title with one of these words in it?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: I <s>really</s> strongly wish that we could just have a pop-up saying "Please don't use that word! Here's why: link" rather than a hard ban. That would treat our users as intelligent people, rather than idiots. However, that's more a comment on Stack Exchange software, rather than "actually" and "really".

Comment: This suggestions is *really* tempting. Must wait a while to calm down and find out what I *actually* think the consequences might be.

Comment: Do you **Really** think this is going to work? The law of unintended consequences tells me people will just use a thesaurus. I would love to see the results of this test though, and see if usage of **genuinely, indeed, in fact, truthfully! etc.** don't spike in usage when the ban is in place.

Comment: @user1873 We can try to avoid that with a good message demonstrating that simply removing the emphasis word is the suggested improvement. But, only trying will tell! And we can always undo the change just as easily.

Comment: Can we extend this to the word "true", to shorten "Is it true that ..." questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the lack of meaninguful negative feedback, and that I've had to nuke three more *really* today, the blacklist is on.

The help text will be

> Words like 'really' or 'actually' are usually superfluous in questions on this site, please avoid them.

[image]

Let me know if anything goes wrong, or if you think the text can be improved.

Comment: Why does "really" have double quotes but then the second time has single quotes in the message?