# Can I ask a question regarding the credibility of a fact that is widely mentioned over the web, yet cannot be verified easily?

Tags: discussion

I asked a site-recommendation question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261580/299237), and was suggested to ask the question on Skeptics Stack Exchange (on its Meta first).

So, is the following question fit for the site, or what needs to be fixed in it to be become fit here?

---

I came to notice through a Facebook post that a renowned scientist and former President of India Mr A.P.J. Adbul Kalam passed away. When I tried to look upon [his Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._P._J._Abdul_Kalam) I noticed this line:

> Kalam's 79th birthday was recognised as *World Student Day* by the United Nations.

The source backing that claim is [here](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-national/tp-tamilnadu/students-recall-kalams-services/article837169.ece), whose content doesn't shed any light on whether UN really recognized that day or not. On further research over web, I found various links which claimed this fact. **It is to be noted that** all those links were either from Indian people, Indian media, Indian websites, or things dominantly dealing with Indian matters. '[Indian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India)' here refers to a South Asian and second largest populated Country in the world.

Failing to find an authentic source, I tried to find what is *World Student Day*. Here are some sources that I found:

- [World Student Day](http://ifesworld.org/en/node/53) (from IFES)
- [Oct 17 – World Student Day](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~hrcf/?p=174) (from Harvard-Radcliffe Christian Fellowship)
- [World Student Day 2015](http://languagescanada.ca/en/language-education-sector/sector-activities/) (from  Languages Canada)

None of them mentioned the term *United Nations (UN)* anywhere in the text.

I lastly looked at the days of [International Observance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_observance) and found the only mention of the word 'Student' in this line:

> November 17   International Students Day

The wiki page of [International Students Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Students%27_Day) again has no mention of Mr Kalam, neither it says that UN has officially observed it.

UNESCO also on its page of [International Days](http://www.unesco.org/new/en/unesco/events/prizes-and-celebrations/celebrations/international-days/) has no mention of the word *Student*.

Questions:

- So, what exactly is the *World Student Day*?
- Did UN really observe Mr Kalam's 79<sup>th</sup> birthday as *World Student Day*?
- Where is the authentic source to back any of the claims?
- Should it be considered a *hoax* to deceive the Indian citizens with false pride and information? (tends to be speculative I suppose)

Comment: I think it is safe to assume readers are familiar with the country of India - even in those countries re-discovered by Columbus.

Comment: @Oddthinking I mentioned about 'India' to avoid any confusion (while mentioning *President of India* shouldn't cause any) because this term is loosely used to refer  the native Americans. Feel free to edit it out on the question now asked [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/28600/27317) if you're satisfied that there would be no confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your second question,

> Did UN really observe Mr Kalam's 79th birthday as World Student Day?

would be on-topic here, but consider [a less incredulous phrasing](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/445/is-there-really-a-reason-why-so-many-questions-really-need-to-include-the-wo).

Comment: Except drop the word ["really"](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/445/is-there-really-a-reason-why-so-many-questions-really-need-to-include-the-wo).